# How can I prevent rubber bands disintegrating?

Tags: repair, storage, durability, rubber-bands

[These](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/341/13390) [two](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/360/13390) answers partially answer this question., but I think it's worth its own question to find more options in a more comprehensive answer.

---

Old Lego rubber bands are known to become brittle over time and break. The two questions linked above indicate that exposure to oxygen or light is the cause, and that sealing rubber bands in an airtight bag is one solution.

In my experience it has only been rubber bands with a square cross-section that decay. I have not (yet) had one break with a round cross-section.

What other ways are there to safely keep rubber bands for long periods of time, both for storage and display?

Comment: I don't think you can keep square rubber bands from breaking. They are clearly made of different material than round ones, that seem to deteriorate with time due to chemical processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to exposure to heat and UV light (as highlighted in the linked question):

- Temperature fluctuations can cause the rubber to expand and contract which will weaken the rubber.
- Certain cleaning solvents used on the model may cause damage to the material, it might be best to remove the rubber bands when cleaning models.

There are specific rubber coatings available that can help maintain the elasticity and flexibility of rubber bands. One particular product that I am familiar with for rubber band magic is '[Elastraflex](https://www.vanishingincmagic.com/magic-accessories/elastraflex-50-oz-bottle/)' which is quite pricey and may not necessarily work for rubber bands manufactured by LEGO.

Unfortunately unlike LEGO bricks, rubber bands have a much shorter lifespan when in use or in storage due to the nature of their material.

It may be more economical to buy a pack of non-LEGO rubber bands that have similar properties to LEGO-made bands and storing unused bands in sealed plastic bags. There is a good study of review of alternative options [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/14659/procuring-alternative-rubber-bands).